# How do you find the solution for $ x+3z+w=0, y+z+2w=0 $?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

They say the answers are $c(-3,-1,1,0)$, $c(-1,-2,0,1) $ when c is an arbitrary constant. I kinda understand you can get the answers by putting $0$ respectively into the variable both of the two equations have and derive other values. However, how do you know they are the only answers? You could say there might be some answers where neither $z$ and $w$ are $0$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find vectors $(x,y,z,w)$, orthogonal to both $\vec{a}=(1,0,3,1)$ and $\vec{b}=(0,1,1,2)$. Extend these two vectors to form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$, say $\{\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}, \vec{d}\}$, and then run Gram Schmidt Orthogonalization to get a orthogonal basis, say $\{\vec{a}^*, \vec{b}^*, \vec{c}^*, \vec{d}^*\}$. Any vector $(x,y,z,w)\in\mathrm{span}(\vec{c}^*, \vec{d}^*)$ will satisfy the two equations given abovr.